# SQL Cast Mystery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a real mystery with the T-SQL below.  As it is, it works with either the `DATAP.Private=1`, or the `cast as int` on `Right(CRS,1)`.  That is, if I uncomment the `DATAP.Private=1`, I get the error `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'M' to data type int`, and if I then remove that cast, the query works again.  With the cast in place, the query only works without the `Private=1`.

I cannot for the life of me see how the `Private=1` can **add** anything to the result set that will cause the error, unless `Private` is ever 'M', but `Private` is a `bit` field!

```
SELECT 
      cast(Right(CRS,1) as int) AS Company
    , cast(PerNr as int) AS PN
    , Round(Sum(Cost),2) AS Total_Cost
FROM 
    DATAP 
    LEFT JOIN BU_Summary ON DATAP.BU=BU_Summary.BU
WHERE 
    DATAP.Extension Is Not Null 
    --And DATAP.Private=1
    And Left(CRS,2)='SB'
    And DATAP.PerNr Between '1' And '9A'
    and Right(CRS,1) <> 'm'
GROUP BY 
      cast(Right(CRS,1) as int)
    , cast(PerNr as int)
ORDER BY 
    cast(PerNr as int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen something like this in the past.  It's possible the `DATAP.Private = 1` clause is generating a query plan that is performing the CRS cast before the `Right(CRS,1) <> 'm'` filter is applied.

It sure **shouldn't** do that, but I've had similar problems in T-SQL I've written, particularly when views are involved.

You might be able to reorder the elements to get the query to work, or select uncast data values into a temporary table or table variable and then select and cast from there in a separate statement as a stopgap.

If you check the execution plan it might shed some light about what is being calculated where.  This might give you more ideas as to what you might change.

Comment: Totally agree. If DATAP.Private is a bit field, it almost certainly generates clustered index scan, and if server is going to do a scan anyway it will also try to apply all transformations in one go, and only then filter it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it may be that when Private = 1, PerNr cannot be anything but a castable number in your data (as it is in the PerNr can equal '9A [or whatever else]', breaking the cast in the group by and order by clauses).

Comment: But the cast on PerNr works with or without the Private = 1 filter.  It's the cast on Right(CRS, 1) that is dependent on Private=1.

Answer (score 0):

CAST('9A' AS int) fails when I tested it. It looks like you're doing unnecessary CASTS for grouping and sorting. Particularly in the GROUP BY, that will at least kill any chance for optimizing.

Comment: You're correct about unnecessary casts.  I've since checked and my CSV tool outputs all numbers without quotes anyway, where I was casting to int to avoid quoting the numbers.

As for optimizing, this comes from an Access query with uglier queries like this nested several queries deep. Optimisation?